# How to print cell output to a file on colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

In Google Colab, I want to execute several lines of python code, both print and function. The goal is to **redirect** the result to a **file**.Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **In the cell** do you want to print to the file write the following:

   ```
   %%capture cap
   ```
2. For print into a file:

   ```
   f = open("output.txt", "w") 
   print(cap, file=f)
   f.close()
   ```

- Note: With very large outputs it may not work very well.
  The object type of variable `c` is **CapturedIO** from IPython.utils.capture